# How to write a reusable html/css/js component in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have some data in my model that is constantly being rendered using the same html/js/css. I'm tempted to come up with a custom templatetag to simplify rendering the model to something like `{% create_component mymodel %}`. But the problem is that css/js is also included and I would like that to be automatically added to the head of the page (not somewhere in the body of the page)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not separate it out and have 3 templatetags? `create_html`, `create_css`, `create_js`, etc?

Comment: Mostly to keep code clean and adhere to DRY. What if I forget one or two of the three tags? What if I don't need to display that component? (I would need to repeat the 'if' 3 times and hope that I don't typo). I'm just trying to see if I can avoid pain that might incur from the naive solution.

Comment: I never did custom django template tags but if you can [re]define django template blocks in them, if in your base template you will have blocks for css, js, you would be able to append to those blocks whatever you want. So then you can do `{% create_component mymodel css_block js_block %}` which will render html on the spot and append proper css and js to the respective blocks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a django [templatetag](https://github.com/ashwoods/django-labjs) for [labjs](http://labjs.com/) using queues. Besides the advantages of reduced resource blocking, it also made it easier to create components that includes it's own javascript without worrying about performance or double calls.

If you load a javascript file twice it ignores the second call, and combining it with django compress you can make "bundles". It's still not perfect, and I'm looking into writing a django app that uses [headjs](http://headjs.com/), and making a more mature or comprehensive app for handling reusable django components that include html and css.

This would work for the js, but for css you could do something similar, a js library for dynamically loading css files.

The advantage of handling this on the client side is that you get the anti-blocking advantages of deferred loading.

If you just want a plain and simple server side way, what you are looking for is a css/js registry. You can easily write a middleware that outputs all the "registered" js and css in the head, and you can include some css/js registering in your custom model templatetag.

You might be able to use or reuse [django-assets](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/django-assets/) for this.